# How does Lean figure out that these variables are equal?

Tags: lean4

This code type checks:

```
inductive MyEq (a : Type) : a -> a -> Type where
  | myRefl (x : a) : MyEq a x x

def concat (p : MyEq a x y) (q : MyEq a y z) : MyEq a x z :=
  match p, q with
  | MyEq.myRefl x, MyEq.myRefl x => MyEq.myRefl x
```

But why? Each instance of `MyEq.myRefl x` on the last line seems to have the wrong type for its context: the expected types are `MyEq a x y`, `MyEq a y z`, and `MyEq a x z`, but the type is `MyEq a x x` in all three cases.

But any slight modification of this code fails to type check, for example

```
def concat (p : MyEq a x y) (q : MyEq a y z) : MyEq a x z :=
  match p, q with
  | MyEq.myRefl y, MyEq.myRefl y => MyEq.myRefl y
```

or

```
def concat (p : MyEq a x y) (q : MyEq a y z) : MyEq a x z := p
```

or

```
def concat (p : MyEq a x y) (q : MyEq a y z) : MyEq a x z :=
  match p, q with
  | MyEq.myRefl w, MyEq.myRefl x => MyEq.myRefl x
```

where `w` here is meant to be a variable introduced by pattern matching.

I know that, by the elimination rule of the identity type, a function with the same type as `concat` should be able to be defined. And I'm assuming that Lean somehow generates a corresponding elimination rule for this type based on the `inductive` statement. But I don't understand why `concat` is able to be defined by this specific code, which seems nonsensical to me.

Specifically what I would like to know is:

1. Why does Lean accept the first code? Is it some kind of "syntax sugar", where Lean goes above and beyond and automatically figures out that `x`, `y`, and `z` are equal? If so then is there a simpler way of writing this that doesn't rely on the interpreter being smart?
2. Why aren't the other three examples I give valid?

Comment: If `p = MyEq.refl x` then it follows that the type of `p` and `MyEq.refl x` are equal, therefore `MyEq a x y = MyEq a x x`, hence `x = y` by looking at the last argument. Similar reasoning applied to `q` yields `x = z`. But you are probably asking: what is the algorithm that allows Lean to figure ths out, yes?

Comment: @AndrejBauer Yes that is what I am asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I probably can't go into the nitty gritty of Lean's code, I think I can explain why what Lean is doing is natural given the recursion rule for equality and that its behavior is predictable and understandable.

### Simple inductive type

Let's start with a simple inductive type and a simple recursive construction:

```
inductive MyContainer (a : Type) : Type where
  | myConst (x : a) (y : a) : MyContainer a

def foo (p : MyContainer a) (f : a -> b): MyContainer b :=
  match p with
  | MyContainer.myConst x y => MyContainer.myConst (f x) (f y)
```

Here `x` and `y` are both acting as variables and can be replaced with anything, including `banana`.  Also, it is helpful to look at the recursor for `MyContainer`.  It is the axiom/rule that does all the work when you want to prove anything about `MyContainer`.

```
#print MyContainer.rec
-- recursor MyContainer.rec.{u} : 
--   {a : Type} →
--   {motive : MyContainer a → Sort u} → 
--   ((x y : a) → motive (MyContainer.myConst x y)) → 
--   (t : MyContainer a) → motive t
```

There is a lot going on here, but the important bit is that to use recursion on `MyContainer`, one is trying to construct a `motive` which is just the output Type/Prop/Sort (which may or may not be dependent on the input).  One also needs to (obviously) supply an input object `t : MyContainer` which is the thing you are recursing over.  Finally, one needs to supply a way to construct an object of the output motive from the input, but note in this case it is not from the input `t` itself, but from the `x` and `y` inside `t`, which makes sense since `t : MyContainer a` is uniquely specified by its inner `x` and `y`.

`match ... with` is just semantic sugar and abstraction around `rec`.  To see what is going on, let's use `pp.all`:

```
set_option pp.all true
#print foo
-- def foo : {a b : Type} → MyContainer a → (a → b) → MyContainer b :=
--   fun {a b : Type} (p : MyContainer a) (f : a → b) =>
--     @foo.match_1.{1}
--       a
--       (fun (p : MyContainer a) => MyContainer b)
--       p
--       fun (x y : a) => @MyContainer.myConst b (f x) (f y)
```

You can look up the automatically generated definition `foo.match_1` yourself, but basically it has a similar type to `MyContainer.rec`.  And we supply it the same sort of objects:

- The motive is `fun (p : MyContainer a) => MyContainer b`, so the output of the `match` is `MyContainer b`.
- The input: `p`.
- The function constructed by the `match` is `fun (x : a) => @MyContainer.myConst b (f x)`.

To really see more of what match is doing, let's look at a slightly different construction where `p` is used more than once.  To do that let's just define a trivial relation

```
def R (t : T) := t = t
```

Now, here is half a construction:

```
def foo' (p : MyContainer a) (h : R p) (f : a -> b): MyContainer b :=
  match p with
  | MyContainer.myConst x y => _
```

If we hover over the `_` we get this goal:

```
a b: Type
p: MyContainer a
f: a → b
x y: a
h: R (MyContainer.myConst x y)
⊢ MyContainer b
```

Notice all `p`s are replaced with `MyContainer.myConst x y`, including our h.  The one exception to this is the original `p` we gave as input to the match statement.  This is also apparent in the generated code for `foo'` (after we finish writing the code same as before):

```
-- def foo' : {a b : Type} → (p : MyContainer a) → @R.{1} (MyContainer a) p → (a → b) → MyContainer b :=
--   fun {a b : Type} (p : MyContainer a) (h : @R.{1} (MyContainer a) p) (f : a → b) =>
--     @foo'.match_1.{1}
--       a
--       (fun (p : MyContainer a) (h : @R.{1} (MyContainer a) p) => MyContainer b)
--       p
--       h
--       fun (x y : a) (h : @R.{1} (MyContainer a) (@MyContainer.myConst a x y)) => @MyContainer.myConst b (f x) (f y)
```

Notice `h` is now an input just like `p` and factors into the motive and the function that match is constructing.

### Dependent Inductive Type

Now let's look at what happens if we have a dependent type whose type parameters and inner values align:

```
inductive MyDepContainer (a : Type) : a -> Type where
  | myConst (x : a) (y : a) : MyDepContainer a x
```

Now the recursor (where I replaced a variable name to make it more readable) looks similar but a bit different :

```
#print MyDepContainer.rec
-- recursor MyDepContainer.rec.{u} :
--   {a : Type} →
--   {x : a} →
--   {motive : MyDepContainer a x → Sort u} →
--   ((y : a) → motive (MyDepContainer.myConst a x y)) →
--   (t : MyDepContainer a x) → motive t
```

The big difference from before is that the function we are constructing is of type `((y : a) → motive (MyDepContainer.myConst a x y))`.  Why do we only have the `y` input and not the `x` input?  Well, we don't need `x` because we already have `x` to specify the type of `t`.  There is nothing we discover about `x` by looking inside `t`.

We use a match on `MyDepContainer` as follows.

```
def bar (p : MyDepContainer a x) (f : a -> b): MyDepContainer b (f x) :=
  match p with
  | MyDepContainer.myConst x y => MyDepContainer.myConst (f x) (f y)
```

While `y` could be replaced with anything, `x` cannot be anything but `x`.   Lean knows this, and we could even just write `_` in place of the first `x` and in place of `(f x)`, which also can't be anything but `f x`.

This is apparent when printing the code for `bar`:

```
set_option pp.all true
#print bar
-- def bar : {a : Type} → {x : a} → {b : Type} → MyDepContainer a x → (f : a → b) → MyDepContainer b (f x) :=
--   fun {a : Type} {x : a} {b : Type} (p : MyDepContainer a x) (f : a → b) =>
--     @bar.match_1.{1}
--       a
--       x
--       (fun (p : MyDepContainer a x) => MyDepContainer b (f x))
--       p
--       fun (y : a) => @MyDepContainer.myConst b (f x) (f y)
```

Again, the function we are constructing which gets applied to `p` doesn't need to know anything about `x`.

### Identity types

Finally, we can get to your type `MyEq`, which is an identity type.  (As an aside, I assume you are familiar at least a little homotopy type theory since you constructed the main object of interest in that field, but if not, see section 1.12 of the [HoTT book](https://homotopytypetheory.org/book/) for more on recursion and induction for this type.)  The recursor for `MyEq` is as follows (where I replaced some of the variable names to make it more readable):

```
recursor MyEq.rec.{u} :
  {a : Type} →
  {x : a} →
  {motive : (y : a) → MyEq a x y → Sort u} →
  motive x (MyEq.myRefl x) → 
  {y : a} → 
  (t : MyEq a x y) → 
  motive y t
```

Now we have two inputs `y` and `t : MyEq a x y` to the recursor (and to the motive).  Just like the previous example, we don't need `x` to construct an element of the motive, but now we don't need `y` either since it is also a parameter to the type.  But here is is especially important that our motive can be dependent on `y`.  In the end we want to construct something that depends on our input `y` (and sometimes on the path `t`).  Let's call the motive `P`. Then we are trying to construct an element (or proof) of `P y t`.  But the function we are constructing is not of that form.  To construct and element/proof of `P y t` it is enough to give a construction of an element of `P x (MyEq.myRefl x)`.  This makes sense if you think of your type as the equality type `x = y`.

Okay, here is a simple example:

```
def baz (p : MyEq a x y) (f : a -> b) : MyEq b (f x) (f y) :=
  match p with
  | MyEq.myRefl x => MyEq.myRefl (f x)
```

Again, we can't supply anything else but `x` as input.  Let's look at the function details:

```
-- def baz : {a : Type} → {x y : a} → {b : Type} → MyEq a x y → (f : a → b) → MyEq b (f x) (f y) :=
--   fun {a : Type} {x y : a} {b : Type} (p : MyEq a x y) (f : a → b) =>
--     @baz.match_1.{1}
--       a
--       x
--       (fun (y : a) (p : MyEq a x y) => MyEq b (f x) (f y))
--       y
--       p
--       fun (_ : Unit) => @MyEq.myRefl b (f x)
```

So per the discussion above, the function we are trying to convey with this match has to have type of the `motive x (myEq.myRefl x)`, which in this case is `MyEq b (f x) (f x)`, that is where `y` is replaced with `x`.

To better see this in action, let's look at on more example which is closer to your example:

```
def baz2 (p : MyEq a x y) (q : MyEq a y z) (f : a -> b) : MyEq b (f x) (f z) :=
  match p with
  | MyEq.myRefl x => _
```

I have only filled in half the proof for the moment.  But if you hover over the `_`, it will tell you what you have to fill in:

```
a: Type
x y z: a
b: Type
p: MyEq a x y
f: a → b
q: MyEq a x z
⊢ MyEq b (f x) (f z)
```

All the `y`s have been replaced with `x` except for `y` and `p` which are the official inputs to the match statement, so `q` now has type `q: MyEq a x z`. (This is similar to what we saw with the simple inductive type example.)
Therefore, if we nest our match one more level, we have to use `MyEq.myRefl x` for `q` since that now matches the type of `q`:

```
def baz2 (p : MyEq a x y) (q : MyEq a y z) (f : a -> b) : MyEq b (f x) (f z) :=
  match p with
  | MyEq.myRefl x =>
    match q with
    | MyEq.myRefl x => _
```

Again, what we need to show is

```
a: Type
x y z: a
b: Type
p: MyEq a x y
f: a → b
q: MyEq a x z
⊢ MyEq b (f x) (f x)
```

where now all `z`s have been replaced with `x` except `z` and `q` which are inputs to our function.

And finally, your match is just basically sugar for nested matches.  You can start to see now what is going on.

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful.